# Play Framework Cannot connect to DB after sometime

Tags: sql-server-2008, playframework, playframework-2.1, ebean

We are facing a strange issue with `Play framework 2.1.0` using `MSSQL` database

Application conf:

```
db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/PlayApp;instance=SQL2008"
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user=sa
db.default.pass=test
db.default.partitionCount=1
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
db.default.acquireIncrement=1
db.default.acquireRetryAttempts=1
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5
```

Below exception:

```
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)

[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 5ms and trying again. Attempts left: 1. Exception: null
[error] application -

! @6h0j5mlj9 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
        at play.api.Configuration$.play$api$Configuration$$configError(Configuration.scala:80) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:558) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:251) ~[play-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(DB.scala:242) ~[play-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
[error] application -
```

I tried to sort the issue but I need to restart my Sql instance everytime I get this error is it some connection pool issue?

Any one to anwser ?

Comment: Please add some solution as my configurations seemed correct but i am having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to change

```
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5
```

by

```
db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds
```

Comment: I have simmilar issue but in my configurations i have db.default.acquireRetryDelay=5 seconds but that doesn't work. Did you find any solution to this problem??